# Running a script off local machine to remote using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

Here is the command I am trying to run

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName DOG-02 C:\Users\user\Documents\PowerShell\PowerShellmenuz.ps1
```

I want to be able to run the script `PowerShellmenuz.ps1` on a remote machine. I am very close but am stuck at this point.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Command looks good, please edit your question and add the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell where is the problem without error output, but probably you've missed first configuration step on remote machine. There things that should be done before executing scripts on remote machine.

- Enabling PowerShell Remoting on the computer that you want access remotely. Open a PowerShell window as **Administrator** – right click the PowerShell shortcut and select *"Run as Administrator"*. And execute the following command:

`Enable-PSRemoting -Force` - it will start service WinRM to allow incoming connections.